# Проверка, разрешена ли отправка сообщений пользователю Вконтакте через API

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Столкнулся с такой задачей при разработке Iframe приложения для ВК. 
Есть задача: запросить у пользователя разрешение на отправку сообщений от лица сообщества с помощью метода `showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox` через API VK. С этим проблем нет:

```
 VK.callMethod("showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox");
```

При повторном открытии приложения нужно проверить, что пользователь уже разрешил отправку (чтобы не открывалось снова окно запроса разрешения), но каким это методом можно сделать - так и не нашел?

Есть вариант проверки с помощью метода `messages.isMessagesFromGroupAllowed`, вызванного с ключом доступа сообщества, но этот вариант подходит для владельцев сообществ, а не для участников (если я правильно понимаю).

Может кто подскажет, каким методом можно проверить что пользователь уже разрешил отправку?

Comment: При создании приложения можно указать обязательную установку и разрешение на отправку сообщение. Для проверки установки можно использовать. 'users.isAppUser'

Comment: Проверку установки я могу проверить из данных от приложения через параметр  [is_app_user] => 1, но это ровным счетом ничего не дает. Например, я участник группы, открыл приложение, мне пришло  [is_app_user] => 0, кликнул по кнопке Разрешить оповещения - разрешить. Открываю снова приложение, параметр  [is_app_user] => 0, но при этом слать мне сообщения от группы можно, но как отследить что данное опция включена - не понятно. Только если зайти в настройки группы параметр Не получать уведомления говорит о том, что мне могут отправлять сообщения.

Comment: Точнее Запретить сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

## Проверка доступа отправки сообщения

Можно использовать `messages.get` с параметром `{"out": 0}` который вернёт список обьект личных сообщений, в котором есть параметр `user_id` - список людей (их id), которые когда либо писали сообщения (и им, соответственно, можно отправлять). Далее через `users.get` получить id пользователя, и циклом искать совпадение.

## Дополнительное решение

```
messages.allowMessagesFromGroup
```

Данный метод разрешает отправку сообщений от группы пользователю, и включает в себя 2 параметра: **group_id** и **key**. Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в Standalone-приложении через Implicit Flow. Требуются права доступа: **messages**.

Comment: Способ через messages.get хорош, но не совсем подходит. Дело в том,  что он делает выборку по отправленным сообщениям, а насколько мне понятно VK.callMethod("showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox"); дает разрешение на отправку. Получается, что сообщений от пользователя может и не быть, но при этом ему можно отправить уведомление.

Comment: И еще у метода messages.get две варианта вызова: 1. с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в Standalone-приложении и 2.  с ключом доступа сообщества. Если пользователь использует Iframe приложение и является участником (не админом) группы, где установлено приложение, то каким образом можно вызвать данный метод?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю необходимого вам метода нету, и первый не совсем подходит (хотя попробуйте использовать ВАШ ключ от сообщества, или почитайте про Callback API), а что насчет второго?

Comment: Ничего не подходит. Если сказать просто: нужно когда пользователь заходит в Iframe-приложение группы, где он простой участник группу (без каких-либо прав), получить каким-то образом параметр, который отвечает за флаг в меню группы Разрешить сообщение или Запретить сообщение. Не понятно как получить его и в документации этого не нашел. Есть метод messages.isMessagesFromGroupAllowed но он требует Standalone-приложения (а у меня Iframe) или ключ доступа группы (что для простого участника - не подходит).

Comment: Наверно придется обрабатывать ответ от метода showAllowMessagesFromCommunityBox с помощью  Callback API и сохранять флаг установки Разрешил сообщение в куку. Хотя мне этот вариант не нравится ибо пользователь в любой момент Запретить сообщения и все, приложение так и не узнает об этом и не покажет ему предложение Разрешить сообщения при следующем открытии.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вызвать `messages.isMessagesFromGroupAllowed` с параметрами: id сообщества, и id текущего пользователя. Метод действует для любого пользователя (проверено). При этом у приложения должен быть доступ к сообщениям сообщества. Подробности в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/messages.isMessagesFromGroupAllowed).

Comment: При этом у приложения должен быть доступ к сообщениям сообщества

Answer (score 0):

Просто отправить метод `messages.send` без параметров `message` и `attachment`, но указать версию, токен и пользователя.

В таком случае, если пользователь не разрешил отправлять ему сообщения, вы получите ошибку 901. Если разрешил, то ошибку 100 или другую, если имеется.